# Android SMS URI locator

Tags: java, android

I have made the app to display all text messages that are currently in my inbox in a `textview`.  In order to do this I had to include the URI.  I am trying to test other phones that I have but are not registered through my celluar carrier (Version) as they do not support the phones I have as they did not come from Verizon.

So my question, Are all URIs the same for android phones?  Here is my code that I am using, if there is a better way to access all sms in the inbox without specifying the URI, I am open to changing my code.

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

while (cur.moveToNext()) {              
    smsAddress = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
    smsBody = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
    txtResults.append(counter + "From", smsAddress)); 
    txtResults.append(counter + "Message", smsBody));           

    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are all URIs the same for android phones? Here is my code that I am using, if there is a better way to access all sms in the inbox without specifying the URI.

Yes there is same for all android phones. This is way to fetch all inbox message. These messages are stored in content provider which allow you to access it's data from other app.

To access data of it, you need to give URI of what data you are looking. If you want all messages whichever are there either sent/inbox/draft then URI of it `Uri.parse("content://sms/");`

To access which are in inbox then do it like below `Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")`

To access which are in sent then do it like below
`Uri.parse("content://sms/sent")`